Test-ComputerSecureChannel / nltest errors out on a single domain controller in forest
I have a freshly installed virtual machine (4 vCPUs, 4 GB RAM). Windows Server 2022 with Desktop Experience, also tried 2025, also tried Core. Fully on-premises, no cloud involved.

The VM has a single network adapter with a static IP. Internet is reachable.
I installed DNS Server, configured forwarders, then assigned the network interface DNS server address of 127.0.0.1 (it does so anyway during promotion to domain controller, tried with and without this step). Name resolution of external hosts works every time fine, jfyi.
VM restarted.
Promoted to an AD domain controller, process went smoothly, domain name is mytest.internal.
Logged in as domain admin, all ok.
This is the only machine in that forest. No computers joined that domain, no other domain controllers.
No other reconfiguration or software installation was done.

I then launch PowerShell with admin privileges on this same VM and run Test-ComputerSecureChannel. I always get the following error:
PS C:\Windows\system32> Test-ComputerSecureChannel
Test-ComputerSecureChannel : Cannot verify the secure channel for the local computer. Operation failed with the following exception: 
The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.
At line:1 char:1
+ Test-ComputerSecureChannel
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (WIN22CORE1:String) [Test-ComputerSecureChannel], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailToTestSecureChannel,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestComputerSecureChannelCommand

Same for nltest /sc_verify and nltest /sc_reset:
C:\windows\system32>nltest /sc_verify:mytest.internal
I_NetLogonControl failed: Status = 1355 0x54b ERROR_NO_SUCH_DOMAIN

Same for netdom:
C:\windows\system32>netdom reset win22core1 /domain:mytest.internal
The secure channel from WIN22CORE1 to MYTEST.INTERNAL was not reset.

The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.

The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.

The command failed to complete successfully.

Here's the network configuration. IPv6 is disabled, I did that as a last attempt, it did not improve things.
PS C:\Windows\system32> ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : WIN22CORE1
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : mytest.internal
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : mytest.internal

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 08-00-27-C7-3B-0B
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.10(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 127.0.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Result of dcdiag:
Directory Server Diagnosis

Performing initial setup:
   Trying to find home server...
   Home Server = WIN22CORE1
   * Identified AD Forest.
   Done gathering initial info.

Doing initial required tests

   Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\WIN22CORE1
      Starting test: Connectivity
         ......................... WIN22CORE1 passed test Connectivity

Doing primary tests

   Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\WIN22CORE1
      Starting test: Advertising
         ......................... WIN22CORE1 passed test Advertising
      Starting test: FrsEvent
         ......................... WIN22CORE1 passed test FrsEvent
      Starting test: DFSREvent
         There are warning or error events within the last 24 hours after the SYSVOL has been shared.  Failing SYSVOL replication problems may cause
         Group Policy problems.
         ......................... WIN22CORE1 failed test DFSREvent
      Starting test: SysVolCheck
         ......................... WIN22CORE1 passed test SysVolCheck
      Starting test: KccEvent
         ......................... WIN22CORE1 passed test KccEvent
      Starting test: KnowsOfRoleHolders
         ......................... WIN22CORE1 passed test KnowsOfRoleHolders
      Starting test: MachineAccount
         ......................... WIN22CORE1 passed test MachineAccount
      Starting test: NCSecDesc
         ......................... WIN22CORE1 passed test NCSecDesc
      Starting test: NetLogons
         ......................... WIN22CORE1 passed test NetLogons
      Starting test: ObjectsReplicated
   Running partition tests on : ForestDnsZones
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : DomainDnsZones
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : Schema
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... Schema passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... Schema passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : Configuration
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... Configuration passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... Configuration passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : mytest
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... mytest passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... mytest passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running enterprise tests on : mytest.internal
      Starting test: LocatorCheck
         ......................... mytest.internal passed test LocatorCheck
      Starting test: Intersite
         ......................... mytest.internal passed test Intersite

dcdiag /test:DNS yields this:
Directory Server Diagnosis

Performing initial setup:
   Trying to find home server...
   Home Server = WIN22CORE1
   * Identified AD Forest.
   Done gathering initial info.

Doing initial required tests

   Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\WIN22CORE1
      Starting test: Connectivity
         ......................... WIN22CORE1 passed test Connectivity

Doing primary tests

   Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\WIN22CORE1

      Starting test: DNS

         DNS Tests are running and not hung. Please wait a few minutes...
         ......................... WIN22CORE1 passed test DNS

   Running partition tests on : ForestDnsZones

   Running partition tests on : DomainDnsZones

   Running partition tests on : Schema

   Running partition tests on : Configuration

   Running partition tests on : mytest

   Running enterprise tests on : mytest.internal
      Starting test: DNS
         ......................... mytest.internal passed test DNS

All the FSMO roles are obviously on this server:
PS C:\Windows\system32>netdom query fsmo
Schema master               WIN22CORE1.mytest.internal
Domain naming master        WIN22CORE1.mytest.internal
PDC                         WIN22CORE1.mytest.internal
RID pool manager            WIN22CORE1.mytest.internal
Infrastructure master       WIN22CORE1.mytest.internal
The command completed successfully.

My question is - why it's failing the secure channel test? How do I fix it? Should I care about it?
To spice up things a bit more, here are my other findings:

If I add another domain controller to the same domain, it returns True for Test-ComputerSecureChannel. The first one continues to fail.
I spotted the same behavior in a production environment with 2 domain controllers that has worked just fine since 2017 and continue to work fine. They were installed by someone else, so it's not my way of doing it. It is Windows Server 2016. The "first" one (the one that holds all FSMO roles) errors out Test-ComputerSecureChannel, the other one works just fine. Their DNS settings point to the other one first, then to themselves. The domain has several hundred PCs and the same number of users, and it works fine. Replication between domain controllers works fine.

For now my hypothesis goes towards that it fails on the server that has a specific FSMO role. I'm going to check it, but it already annoys me and took a lot of time.
Appreciate any insights on that. Thank you in advance.

Running these commands on the AD server that has the PDC function gives these results. I cant remember seeing any documentation on this, but it kinda makes sense, since your local computer and the server are the same, there is no secure channel between the two.

@Silbee Thank you. I'd expect that Microsoft handles that and displays more user-friendly message such as "querying computer secure channel on a PDC is not supported", not that the domain doesn't exist. But, well, it is what it is. It's been only 25 years of Active Directory, it's still in beta it seems.
